# Continue the row of numbers: 1, 3, 9, 13, 65, ...?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, formation-of-numbers, sequence

Yesterday, I stumbled across a series of numbers that I could not solve. Maybe one of you can figure it out?

> 1, 3, 9, 13, 65, …?

Answer (score 5):

The sequence is short but this could be how it works

> 1 **+ 2** = 3
>  3 **x 3** = 9
>  9 **+ 4** = 13
>  13 **x 5** = 65
>  65 **+ 6** = **71**

This is confirmed by

> OEIS [here](https://oeis.org/A047905) and [here](https://oeis.org/A134190) with the logic behind both sequences being similar (the second one having extra conditions).